# adding two 4-vectors with sse using pointers

Tags: c++, assembly, sse

This piece of code (doubling a 4-vector) works:

```
__declspec(align(16)) struct vec4 { float a[4]; };

int main()
{
    vec4 c;
    c.a[0]=2;
    c.a[1]=0;
    c.a[2]=0;
    c.a[3]=0;

    __asm {
        movaps xmm1, c

        addps xmm1, xmm1
        movaps c, xmm1
    }
}
```

But this piece (doing the same but now with a pointer to the aligned data) doesn't:

```
__declspec(align(16)) struct vec4 { float a[4]; };

int main()
{
    vec4* c = new vec4;
    c->a[0]=2;
    c->a[1]=0;
    c->a[2]=0;
    c->a[3]=0;

    __asm {
        movaps xmm1, c

        addps xmm1, xmm1
        movaps c, xmm1
    }
}
```

Why?

I need it to work with pointers, because I can't use the aligned data itself as a function argument.

Comment: Why aren't you using SSE intrinsics? Just wondering... I don't write SSE code.

Comment: Obviously the same code can't work for both cases because they differ in level of indirection. You will have to load the pointer into a register first and use another indirection on that. For example,`mov eax, c; movaps xmm1, [eax]` ...

Comment: When writing a somewhat more complicated vectorized algorithm, when the pressure at the registers increases, there often is too much stuff moving in and out of the registers, which I can easily prevent by writing it in assembly myself.

Comment: @Jester: Thanks. Did it this way:

mov eax, c;
movaps xmm1, [eax]
addps xmm1, xmm1
movaps [eax], xmm1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointer in ASM must be treated accordingly to certain rules, which you can learn pretty much by learning [how "MOV" works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOV_(x86_instruction)).

By the rules of Assembler, you first need to copy pointer to cpu register. then you can use it to point at memory location.

```
vec4 *d = ...;
__asm {
    mov eax, d
    movaps xmm1, [eax]

    addps xmm1, xmm1
    movaps [eax], xmm1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that objects created by a heap allocator (like new and malloc) don't follow the alignment you specify. You only get your alignment with a stack allocated object (your first example).

C++11 has support for explicit alignment of objects allocated through the heap with alignas, but this is not implemented by VC++ yet. It'll work with some compilers, and not others.

**You have a couple of options.**

*The easiest one: create your heap allocated object as you did, and copy it to a stack allocated object before using it:*

```
vec4* c = new vec4;
c->a[0]=2;
c->a[1]=0;
c->a[2]=0;
c->a[3]=0;

vec4 d = *c;
// process with d
```

The other option is to have your vec4 struct include enough additional memory so that you will be guaranteed to have 16 bytes on a 16 byte alignment. I believe that new guarantees a minimum of 4 byte alignment, so 28 bytes would do it. You would then have to manually check the pointer to see where you want to store the data to be used with sse.